# Ask for an update to schedule an interview

Tags: interviewing

I was approached by a head of a company asking if I were interested in a particular job- I said yes but when I was approached I was on my way to a 3 week vacation so I politely informed him saying I will submit my application once I am back and this was agreed upon.

Once I got back, I promptly submitted my application and I got a positive response from him directly stating he will call me for an interview soon and he has a particular job role in mind for me. Now it has been 2 months and I have not heard from him - should I approach him again ?

I also know they are currently recruiting for a lot of different roles and he might be busy in various interviews but I feel stood up as he had approached me back in May and encouraged me to apply and now I don't hear anything at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: Hi @gnat, the above posts talks about a follow up after the interview . In this case, its a follow up for an interview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are still interested or want clarity about the situation, ask**. 
Weigh your need to get an update versus the likely degree of how busy you counterpart is and how much you want to disturb him. If you don't mind waiting a couple of days for an answer, use an asynchronous way of communication like mail, text message or even a letter if that is still a thing in your location. If you need an answer quick to make decisions about your life, e.g. a contract renewal, then use a direct way of communication like a phone call. 
Be polite and everything is fine. It's been quite a while and asking to be in the loop is totally fine. If they cannot give a definitive answer now, it is also fine to ask about their process and a likely date where they can give you a decision.

**If you don't care anymore**, because you have a great other offer or you feel they show bad organisation / culture for having you wait that long, you don't *need* to contact them, but it would still be *polite* to **notify them that you are no longer available**.
In general this mainly applies if you had some personal exchange (like in OP's case) or heard back from them at all in response to an application. If they haven't bothered to communicate your way at all so far, you don't need to bother with telling them you're no longer available either. 
(It doesn't hurt you, and therefore you still can, but politeness only needs to go so far. Depending on the timing, it might still be a good idea to close that chapter and not have to reject an offer later).

Answer (score 3):

> i promptly submitted my application and I got a positive response from him directly stating he will call me for an interview soon and he has a particular job role in mind for me. Now it has been 2 months and I have not heard from him - should I approach him again ?

Yes, you should.

If you feel he may be busy, prefer an asynchronous medium such as email over phone call or walking in.

Comment: I am inclined to email him , just wondering if it would be rude/needy or not

Comment: @user107047 From your description so far, it won't sound needy. You can politely ask to check on the status of the discussion you had. State that you are wondering if the position is still available. OTOH, it's possible that company head may be under the assumption that you are no longer available

Answer (score -1):

Don't waste any more of your time.

The head was partly fishing for cv's to check out the quality of the pond.

That post has most likely been filled...

Comment: it wasn't a recruiter , he was the head of the department from the company recruiting for his team

Comment: OK, edited... @user107047